# Something wrong with my int main(){}

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char sell;
int crew;
char you [50];
int ships =1;
int money;
int choice;

class ship{
public:
void sell_shii(){
cout<<"Do you wish to seel your ship?"<<endl;
cout<<"1to sell ship and 2to cancel"<<endl;


cin>>sell;
if (sell==1 && ships >0){
cout<<"You sold your ship"<<endl;
ships+=sell;



}else{
cout<<"You didnt sell your ship"<<endl;
}
}
}





int main()
{



cout<<"What is your name captain?"<<endl;
cin>>you;
cout<<"Welcome captain "<<you<<endl;

cout<<"You have "<<ships<<"ship/s";

cout<<"What would you like to do?\n 1 buy ships 2 sell ships\n 3 battle\n
cin<<choice;

switch (choice)

case 1:
buyship()
break;
case 2:
sellshii()
break;
case 3;
battle();

return 0;

}
```

My "{" where the int main is doesnt seem to work, what have i done?

Erros that appear are

```
C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\New folder.IPA\C++\Ship game\main.cpp|37|error: new types may not be defined in a return type|
C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\New folder.IPA\C++\Ship game\main.cpp|37|error: extraneous `int' ignored|
C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\New folder.IPA\C++\Ship game\main.cpp|37|error: `main' must return `int'|
C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\New folder.IPA\C++\Ship game\main.cpp|37|error: return type for `main' change to "int"
```

Comment: Thnaks for that :) it sorted it.

Comment: Please take the time to properly indent your code.

Comment: -1: for being a low-quality, "debug my code" question.

Answer (score 2):

You need a semicolon at the end of your class definition (the final `}` before you declare `main`).

Without that, it thinks you're trying to define the class as part of the return type of `main`, because there's no separator between the two, hence the error message:

`error: new types may not be defined in a return type`

And, of course, it also complains because you're not returning an `int` type from `main` as well (after it tosses away the `int` because you've already, albeit unwittingly, specified a return type):

`error: extraneous 'int' ignored`
`error: 'main' must return 'int'`
`error: return type for 'main' change to "int"`